# Get Mailquota from Exchange that is connected to an Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, active-directory, exchange-server

I have to write a ASP.NET application in C# that returns the mailquota of a exchange mailaccount. The exchange is connected to a active directory and the mailquota is set to default.

I have tried to do this but i cant get the needed fields, someone an idea?

```
DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "FQD"); 

DomainControllerCollection dcc = DomainController.FindAll(context);

DirectorySearcher dSearch = dcc[0].GetDirectorySearcher();
dSearch.Filter= string.Format("sAMAccountName={0}",model.UserName);
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mDBOverHardQuotaLimit");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mDBStorageQuota");
dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mDBOverQuotaLimit");
dSearch.SizeLimit = 10;

SearchResult sr = dSearch.FindOne();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow. You're saying the data isn't returned? If they're using defaults (there's an `mdbUseDefaults` or similiar attribute), then you need to walk back to the user's mailbox database to get their quota. That link is stored in the `homeMdb` attribute. You'll need Exchange View-Only permissions to see those objects, though.

Comment: I connect to the AD with the user credentials. The mdbUseDefaults property delivers true but i don´t know how to get to the mail quota value.

Comment: Well the user's creds aren't going to have enough access to read the quotas off their mailbox database. You get their database from `homeMdb` on their account, and then the same quota attributes are set on that object.